# installing nvidia GT 740m driver on Ubuntu 13.10 get Black screen after login!

Tags: nvidia

I'm using HP Pavilion with nvidia GeForce GT 740m, after finish installing ubuntu 13.10 try to install nvidia driver 331.20 but i got black screen after login to ubuntu.
how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: This should do what you need: http://askubuntu.com/a/375887/225284

Comment: after installing driver there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved by installing Bumblebee. add the ppa to my system from the Xorg-Edgers PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

check which nvidia driver you already installed run this command `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` and remove it in my case i had nvidia-current .

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

then install bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-319
```